# How to append only once in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

While I understand the problem the code is having I can't figure out how to correct it. The `append` is writing to 8 rows. There are exactly 8 cells which have been checked so it writes to 8 rows.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if i == cell.value:
            print("found match")
        else:
            y=[]
            y.append(i)
            ws.append(y)
            wb.save("Trying web.xlsx")
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MarcelP the excel file is printing the string in `i` 8 times. i.e. 8 rows with the same string. It was an indentation error as pointed out below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in python, indentation matters.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    y=[]
    for cell in row:
        if i == cell.value:
            print("found match")
        else:
            y.append(i)
     ws.append(y)
wb.save("Trying web.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It is however still giving the same output. I assume its because the indentation needs to be further back? Just checked it, yes it needs to be at the same indentation as `for row.....`

Comment: whether wb.append whould be further back I cannot say for sure because you haven't posted an MCVE but the save call should indeed be further back and I have changed it